# does any similar broker in mysql working like postgresql FDW for ETL?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

while I use postgresql for ETL , I use postgresql FDW to make a database copy for further analysis in postgresql.
However, if I need to do the same thing in mysql, is there any recommendation daemon for my request:
The new database copy in mysql is writable, and BI engineers can make a new table without interfering the original mysql database(I mean the new table in ETL mysql won't appear in original mysql database. )
I thought a while for an answer and I didn't have a perfect one. Could anyone give me some idea? thanks for your help.

Comment: Should work with a [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html)

Comment: I've voted to migrate the question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/ - You should get better help there.